# Bash: testing if executed command was succesfull

Tags: mysql, sql, bash

I have the following script:

```
if [ `mysql -u root -p < test.sql` ]; then
    echo "success"
else
    echo "some error"
fi
```

How can I check in the `if` if the command went well or there was some sql error?

Comment: I think just `if mysql -u root -p < test.sql ; then` would do it. You don't want the back ticks unless you want the `if` to test the *output* of `mysql`. To check for success, assuming `mysql` follows convention, you want the *return* value of `mysql`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need the `test` command, i.e. `[` here.

Assuming that `mysql` produces a non-zero exit code in case of failure and 0 on success, then you can say:

```
if mysql -u root -p < test.sql; then
    echo "success"
else
    echo "some error"
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way this is typically done is with the "&&" and "||" separators. For example:

```
mysql -u root -p < test.sql && echo "success" || echo "some error"
```

If the mysql command exits with status 0, then "success" will be printed. If it doesn't, "some error" will be printed.